# Cannot ping gateway

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan

I have two switchs cisco 2960 (sw-120 and IDF1-SW) and router cisco 1841 (IDF1-R).

fa0/24 at sw-120 connected via fa0/7 at IDF1-SW

fa0/7 and fa0/24 at IDF1-SW switched to trunk mode

fa0/24 at sw-120 switched to trunk mode too

fa0/1 at sw-120 switched to access to vlan 120

Router(IDF1-R) configured to accept traffic from vlan 120 by subinterface fa0/1.120

```
IDF1-R(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1q 120
IDF1-R(config-subif)#ip ad 10.6.1.26 255.255.255.252
```

Laptop3 configuration is

```
IP : 10.6.1.25   
Subnetmask : 255.255.255.252
Gateway : 10.6.1.26
```

**Problem : I can not ping gateway(10.6.1.26) from Laptop**

[image]

[image]

**Update**

```
sw-120#show spanning-tree vlan 120
VLAN0120
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    32888
             Address     0007.EC16.0917
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32888  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 120)
             Address     0007.EC16.0917
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19        128.24   P2p

sw-120#
```

Update 2.

Here is  IDF1-SW running config
    IDF1-SW#sh ru
    Building configuration...

```
Current configuration : 1118 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname IDF1-SW
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 120
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
end
```

Here is  sw-120 running config

```
sw-120>en
sw-120#sh ru
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1430 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname sw-120
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 120
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 119
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 118
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 117
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 116
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 114
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 113
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
end
```

Comment: on sw-120, type show spanning-tree vlan 120, and post the result

Comment: @RonTrunk, Please look at the updated topic

Comment: In your question you have written `fa0/1 and fa0/24 at IDF1-SW switched to trunk mode` - Did you mean `fa0/7` instead of `fa0/1` ? Also can you show the configuration of each port?

Comment: @jwbensley, Sorry it's my fall. Yes I mean fa0/7. Yes, sure I can, please look at the updated topic

Comment: According to the show spanning-tree command, your switch is not forwarding packets out of port Fa0/1.  Since your switch is configured correctly, that suggests there's a physical connection problem.  Recheck your physical connection. Also type "show int fa 0/1" and post that output.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The solution is VTP domains. You should create VTP domains. IDF1-SW should be in mode vtp-server and sw-120 in mode vtp-client

Comment: Remember to flag this as solved.